# Micro entity status for provisional patent application

Tags: provisional-application, micro-entity

I am part of a small startup and we are in the process of filing our IPs. We fit the micro category as none of the inventors have any patents filed but have submitted 5 provisional applications. Is there a limit on the number of provisional patent applications that one can file as a micro entity?

Answer (score 2):

The complete definition for micro entity eligibility is available here:

https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s509.html#ch500_d1ff69_210b3_1ca

By my reading, you are allowed any number of provisionals that have not yet matured into non-provisional applications without giving up micro entity status thereby. Naturally, you must still meet all other criteria to be considered micro entity.

Also, since you seem to have a company ("startup"), you should investigate whether you need to have representation to file.